# bubble sort on a linked list by swapping nodes in java

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

I wrote a code for bubble sort on a linked list, as follows:

```
public class BubbleLinkedSort {
    public static void swap(Node head, Node current, Node next, Node prev){
        if(current == head){
            current.next = next.next;
            next.next = current;
        }
        else{
            prev.next = current.next;
            current.next = next.next;
            next.next = current;
        }
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(Node head){
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("List is empty");
            return;
        }
        else if(head.next == null){
            System.out.println("only one element in LL");
            return;
        }
        else{
            boolean sorted = false;

            while(!sorted){
                sorted = true;
                Node prev = null;
                Node next = head.next;
                Node current = head;

                while(next != null){
                    if(current.data <= next.data){
                        prev = current;
                        current = current.next;
                        next = next.next;
                    }
                    else{
                        swap(head,current,next,prev);
                        if(current == head)
                        {
                            head = next;
                        }
                        prev = next;
                        next = current.next;
                        sorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is,when the input(unsorted linked list)  has first element smaller then the second element the output

returned is right.for ex:

if input is <1,4,3,2,1> output is <1,1,2,3,4>, which is expected,

but when the input has first element greater then the secong element it gives wrong answer.for ex

if input is <2,1,4,3> then output is <2>.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your swap method doesn't return anything. So `head` is not updated. You can make it return value of the method like:

```
public static Node swap(Node head, Node current, Node next, Node prev){
   if(current == head){
        current.next = next.next;
        next.next = current;
        return next;
    }
    else{
        prev.next = current.next;
        current.next = next.next;
        next.next = current;
        return head;
    }
}
```

and then in method `bubbleSort()` assign it to head like:

```
head = swap(head,current,next,prev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sorts the list correctly, but when the local `head` variable gets assigned a different node reference, this does not alter the *caller's* `head` variable.

You can solve this in at least two ways:

1. Have `bubbleSort` *return* the `head` of the sorted list, so the caller can assign it to their own `head` variable
2. Create a `LinkedList` class that has a `head` member, and defined the `bubbleSort` method on that class: it can then alter that `head` member.

The first idea needs these changes:

```
    public static Node bubbleSort(Node head){
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("List is empty");
            return head; // <--
        }
        else if(head.next == null){
            System.out.println("only one element in LL");
            return head; // <--
        }
        else {
            // ...unchanged code...
        }
        return head; // <-- return the head of the sorted list
     }
```

And caller needs to capture the return value:

```
    head = bubbleSort(head);
```